# Vertical align text in a div style table

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to vertically align all text.

If I remove float:left; then the whole table disappears?

```css
.div-table{
  display:table;         
  width:auto;         
  background-color:#ffffff;               
  border-spacing:20px;
}
.div-table-row{
  display:table-row;
  width:auto;
  clear:both;
}
.div-table-col{
  float:left;
  display:table-column;         
  width:180px;         
  background-color:LightSteelBlue;  
  height:60px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
      <div class="div-table">
             <div class="div-table-row">
                <div class="div-table-col" align="center">Mortgage Lender</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Type</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Initial Period (mths)</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Initial Rate (%)</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">SVR (%)</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Max Amount (£'s)</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Max LTV (%)</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Monthly Repayment (£'s)</div>
             </div>
            <div class="div-table-row">
                 <div class="div-table-col">Nationwide</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">Fixed</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">24</div>
                 <div class="div-table-col">1.99</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">3.99</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">1000000</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">65</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">Calc</div>
            </div>
            <div class="div-table-row">
                 <div class="div-table-col">Nationwide</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">Fixed</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">24</div>
                 <div class="div-table-col">1.99</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">3.99</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">1000000</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">65</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">Calc</div>
            </div>
            <div class="div-table-row">
                 <div class="div-table-col">Nationwide</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">Fixed</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">24</div>
                 <div class="div-table-col">1.99</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">3.99</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">1000000</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">65</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">Calc</div>
            </div>
            <div class="div-table-row">
                 <div class="div-table-col">Nationwide</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">Fixed</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">24</div>
                 <div class="div-table-col">1.99</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">3.99</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">1000000</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">65</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">Calc</div>
            </div>
            <div class="div-table-row">
                 <div class="div-table-col">Nationwide</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">Fixed</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">24</div>
                 <div class="div-table-col">1.99</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">3.99</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">1000000</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">65</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">Calc</div>
            </div>
            <div class="div-table-row">
                 <div class="div-table-col">Nationwide</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">Fixed</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">24</div>
                 <div class="div-table-col">1.99</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">3.99</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">1000000</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">65</div>
                <div class="div-table-col">Calc</div>
            </div>

      </div>
```

I am using div to make the table for valid reasons, so please no *"you should use a `<table>` for tabular data."* :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **th (display : table-header-group;)**: i.e.

```
.div-table{
  display:table;
}
.div-table-row{
  display:table-row;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
}
.thead{
  display : table-header-group;
  background:red;
}
.tbody{
  display : table-row-group;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background:green;
}
.div-table-cell
{
  display:table-cell;         
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

[see this code](http://plnkr.co/edit/qXzp12qd45tMv3Ev0GyZ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If the text is going to be always on a single line You can add:

```
.div-table-col {        
    line-height: 60px;
    }
```

Comment: Ah good idea. That will do for now thanks :) - although my table is now not in the centre of the page? :S

Answer (score 0):

Your elements with class .div-table-col are synonymous with table cells, not columns.  If you change the display to table-cell instead of table-column you will get a tabular layout and you won't need float:left anymore.